# Array in a react state is not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs

I basically try to update filter the items from the all locations array to dropDownLocation array, but it is not updating correctly. on the first change in input field it wrongly update the array and the second change it does not update it.

[image: it shows me this output but i don't know why it is so]

```
 import logo from "./logo.svg";
        import "./App.css";
        import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
        
    function App() {
      // location entered by the user
      const [location, setlocation] = useState("");
    
      const [allLocations, setallLocations] = useState(["F-1", "F-2", "G-1", "G-2"]);
    
      const [dropDownLocations, setdropDownLocations] = useState([]);
    
      const filterLocations = (userInput) => {
        console.log("user input ", location);
    
        allLocations.map((i) => {
          if (i.includes(location)) {
            console.log("true at ", i);
            setdropDownLocations([...dropDownLocations, i]);
          } else {
            setdropDownLocations([]);
          }
        });
    
        console.log("after map ", dropDownLocations);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>
            <input
              value={location}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setlocation(e.target.value);
                filterLocations(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <ul>
              {dropDownLocations.map((i) => (
                <li key={i}>{i}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need to make that complicated, Just filter the array based on the user's input**

```
const filterLocations = (userInput) => {
  setdropDownLocations(
    allLocations.filter((location) => location.includes(userInput))
  );
};
```

I made it simpler for you in this working example:

[image: Edit empty-architecture-l0q8l]

Comment: Thank you that's work fine but I got 1 more issue, the issue is that you all first type something that works fine, but when I erase all input text it shows all the item displayed.

Comment: What is that? It's not filtered when the input is empty?

Comment: yes it is not filtered when we empty the input field

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that your `onChange` handler is defined right in the JSX, causing React to recreate a new function at every render (same goes for `filterLocations` one).

You should always try to extract every single piece of JS logic outside of the component, or at least memoize them, here's how:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

const ALL_LOCATIONS = ['F-1', 'F-2', 'G-1', 'G-2'];

function App() {
  // location entered by the user
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  // locations shown to the user in dropdown (filterable)
  const [dropDownLocations, setDropDownLocations] = useState([]);

  const onLocationInputChange = useCallback(
    (ev) => {
      // In case no target passed to callback, do nothing
      if (!ev || !ev.target || !ev.target.value) {
        return;
      }

      const userInput = ev.target.value;

      // Filter so that if user input matches part of the location
      // it gets not filtered out
      setDropDownLocations([
        ...ALL_LOCATIONS.filter(
          (loc) =>
            loc.startsWith(userInput) ||
            loc.endsWith(userInput) ||
            loc.indexOf(userInput) !== -1
        ),
      ]);

      // Finally update the location var
      setLocation(userInput);
    },
    [setDropDownLocations]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input value={location} onChange={onLocationInputChange} />
        <ul>
          {dropDownLocations.map((loc) => (
            <li key={`${location}-${loc}`}>{loc}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setState` is an asynchronous function and so your current implementation isn't working properly as you are trying to read the `state` before it is updated.

Update your `filterLocations` function like following:

```
const filterLocations = (e) => {
  const location = e.target.value;
  const filteredLocation = allLocations.filter(i => i.includes(location));
  setlocation(location);
  setdropDownLocations(filteredLocation)
};
```

And update your `input` tag like following:

```
<input value={location} onChange={filterLocations} />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because for each location, you are setting dropdown location, and if it doesn't contain the location, you set it to empty array [] again.

```
       allLocations.map((i) => {
          if (i.includes(location)) {
            console.log("true at ", i);
            setdropDownLocations([...dropDownLocations, i]);
          } else {
            setdropDownLocations([]);
          }
        });
```

A better approach would be:

```
setDropDownLocation([...allLocations].filter((i) => i.includes(userInput))
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is some mistakes what you have done, I have made some changes try to run the code which I have written.**

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ALL_LOCATIONS = ['F-1', 'F-2', 'G-1', 'G-2'];

function App() {
  // location entered by the user
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [dropDownLocations, setDropDownLocations] = useState([]);

  function onLocationInputChange(event){
    setLocation(event.target.value);

    setDropDownLocations(ALL_LOCATIONS.filter((item)=>item.includes(event.target.value)))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input value={location} onChange={onLocationInputChange} />
        <ul>
          {dropDownLocations.map((loc) => (
            <li key={`${location}-${loc}`}>{loc}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @Sami Malik I hope this will help you!!

Comment: You are always Welcome @SamiMalik.

Comment: one question i want to ask is that if setter function of the states are asynchronous, but it update the UI on the spot, can you please tell me that how it update the UI but not update the state value on exact that render

Comment: Thanks for asking ! when we usually make Api calls in that case it takes little bit time where actually asynchronous functions plays a good role but here is not that scene and if we take a look at React as soon as the state is updated React renders the component, So according to our code UI is updated.

Comment: @SamiMalik are you are a React beginner?

Comment: Nice copy/paste bro :')

Comment: It's your choice @SkyzohKey.